# How to make type optional in typeof typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a code User.container.:

```js
const mapState = (state: AppStateType) => ({
  users: getUsers(state),
  pageSize: getPageSize(state),
  isFetching: getIsFetching(state)
})
const mapDispatch = {
  toggleFollowingInProgress,
}
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

export type PropsType = PropsFromRedux & {
  onPageChanged?: (page: number) => void
}
```

in file Users.tsx i make this:

```js
import { PropsType } from './Users.container'
const Users = (props: PropsType) => {
...
}
```

The variable isFetching is not required for Users.tsx. But the compiler throws an error because i can not through ? make mapState isFetching optional.
What to do? I need to get rid of code duplication

Comment: You can use the Partial type, or you could use Omit and isFetching, and then include it as an optional property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options. You could make that property optional itself. But if you want `isFetching` to be required in the original context you could make another a separate type. I tend to create my types via `type` or `interface` rather than rely on the `typeof` operator.

That being said, Typescript created `Utility Types`.

> TypeScript provides several utility types to facilitate common type
> transformations. These utilities are available globally.

`Partial` is a `Utility Type` for the purpose of:

> Constructs a type with all properties of T set to optional. This utility will
> return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

So you could write

```
const Users = (props: Partial<PropsType>) => {
```

Just keep in mind that will make all the properties optional, not just `isFetching`.

Comment: Because of this, I got problems with number | undefined instead of number, typeof turned out to be very bad for this task. Thanks, I writing types manually